# How to fetch response using Retrofit2 + RXJava2 but fetching response in Postman

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am trying to fetch JSON response from the server for networking I am using Retrofit2 and Rxjava2 to fetch data from the server. Below is my JSON response from the server.

```
{
"status": "Success",
"panHolderName": "xxxxxx",
"dateOfBirth": "xx-xx-xxxx",
"gender": "xxx",
"residence": null,
"occupation": "xxxx",
"address": "xxxxxxx",
"pincode": "xxxxxx"
}
```

When I am using API in Postman it is fetching above response properly but when I am using RXJAva2 and retrofit to fetch response it is showing `panHolderName` field only even if there is no error showing. Why are other fields' data not showing up?

Below is my code:

**RetrofitClient.class**

```
public class RetrofitClient {

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getInstance(){

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(22, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(22, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(22, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    if(retrofit == null)
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://68.169.58.46:8080/portal/androidIntegrationAPI/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();

    return retrofit;
  }

}
```

**ApiService.class**

```
public interface ApiService {     

             @POST("getPanDetails")
             Observable<PanDetails> getDetails(@Body JsonObject jsonObject);
         }
```

**PanDetails.class**

```
public class PanDetails {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
String status;

@SerializedName("panHolderName")
@Expose
String panHolderName;

@SerializedName("dateOfBirth")
@Expose
String dateOfBirth;

@SerializedName("gender")
@Expose
String gender;

@SerializedName("residence")
@Expose
String residence;

@SerializedName("occupation")
@Expose
String occupation;

@SerializedName("address")
@Expose
String address;

@SerializedName("pincode")
@Expose
String pincode;

public PanDetails(String status, String panHolderName, String dateOfBirth, String gender, String residence,
                  String occupation, String address, String pincode) {
    this.status = status;
    this.panHolderName = panHolderName;
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.residence = residence;
    this.occupation = occupation;
    this.address = address;
    this.pincode = pincode;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getPanHolderName() {
    return panHolderName;
}

public void setPanHolderName(String panHolderName) {
    this.panHolderName = panHolderName;
}

public String getDateOfBirth() {
    return dateOfBirth;
}

public void setDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) {
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public String getResidence() {
    return residence;
}

public void setResidence(String residence) {
    this.residence = residence;
}

public String getOccupation() {
    return occupation;
}

public void setOccupation(String occupation) {
    this.occupation = occupation;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getPincode() {
    return pincode;
}

public void setPincode(String pincode) {
    this.pincode = pincode;
}
}
```

**PersonalInfo.class**

```
  private void sendPan(String str1){

    Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
    ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.addProperty("panNo",str1);

    apiService.getDetails(jsonObject).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                     .subscribe(new Observer<PanDetails>() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                                         }

                                         @Override
                                         public void onNext(PanDetails value) {

                                                 prg.dismiss();

                                                 name.setText(value.getPanHolderName());
                                                 Log.d("name",nam);
                                                 mydob.setText(value.getDateOfBirth());
                                                 address.setText(value.getAddress());
                                                 pin.setText(value.getPincode());
                                                 if(value.getGender().equals("Male")){
                                                     gender.setSelection(1);
                                                 }
                                                 else{
                                                     gender.setSelection(2);
                                                 }

                                          
                                         }

                                         @Override
                                         public void onError(final Throwable e) {

                                                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                       @Override
                                                       public void run() {
                                                           prg.dismiss();
                                                           TastyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),
                                                                   TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG,TastyToast.INFO).show();
                                                       }
                                                   });  


                                         }

                                         @Override
                                         public void onComplete() {

                                         }
                                     });
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the issue ?

Comment: Except `panHolderName` I am unable to fetch other fields.

Comment: check the field types in postman like string ,int or boolean and cross check in your pojo class

Comment: how can i check data type of response fields.

Comment: When I am trying to log `panHolderName` filed its  showing something like this `11056-11056/com.app.esfita W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:51): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=255 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c134,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0
`

Comment: can you copy the response from postman and paste in your question ?

Comment: I have posted postman response above plz go through my post.

Comment: Please share the code for RetrofitClient.getInstance().

Comment: @KishanMaurya, I have updated post plz go through it.

Comment: Try to log what you get from server. I think you have issues with view not data.

Comment: Can you share any pan. I tried with pan. 
{
    "status": "No cibil record found!!!",
    "panHolderName": "",
    "dateOfBirth": null,
    "gender": null,
    "residence": null,
    "occupation": null,
    "address": null,
    "pincode": null
}

So till onNext, I am getting data.

Comment: yeah AFPPV8749B u can use this and let me know if u r able  to get info.

Comment: I tried with a given pan. I am getting all data. The issue may be in view.

Comment: If u r using postman then i am also getting all data.How about getting data using Retrofit+rxjava

Comment: I tried in the app only. So I am getting all data inside onNext()

Comment: but I m not getting it in log also could u plz post ur answer so that I can correct mine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216548/discussion-between-kishan-maurya-and-digvijay).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is throwing error after

```
name.setText(value.getPanHolderName());
```

that's why it is not printing other values. You need to observe on the main thread as you are setting UI data.

Add in build.gradle

```
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1"
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.1"
```

and

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```